# Censored logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, survival, censoring

I have the following problem:

We have data with a 0-1 outcome which can occur precisely once. It can occur at any time within a certain time period (say 3 years). For this data set, for some observations we have been able to observe it over the full time period, some for less, so for those observations where we have only observed for 1 year the event might occur in the next two.

If this was a poisson regression then we could use an offset to weight the observations accordingly, but for a logistic regression this is not possible, and using standard weighting isn't quite equivalent to what is occurring.

So what's the best approach here? Pretend the data is poisson, weight the logistic regression by exposure, or some other approach?

Comment: This seems like survival analysis, where patients are followed up to see if any of them die. The study duration here is 3 years but not all patients are followed up for 3 years, some are followed-up for only 1 year. Survival analysis techniques would be useful here.

Comment: Note--to add to what @rnso has helpfully said--that your observations are not the outcomes, but rather the *times*.  This doesn't sound like logistic regression at all.